# How can I edit the EXISTS clause produced by NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can we override the usage of the **HqlExists** class for it's usage creating an **EXISTS** clause in a given NHibernate configuration/dialect?

The driver being used *requires that only a single column be returned when using an EXISTS clause*.  Because the target is using compound keys, multiple columns are selected in the subquery.

```sql
FROM EXISTS (SELECT a,b,c,d FROM ....
```

The end goal is to create the syntax

```sql
FROM EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...
```

My current solution without modifying the source can be applied to a specific context target but adds roughly 2 seconds to the query time:

```cs
public class ExistsModifierInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    private readonly ExistsModificationVisitor existsModificationVisitor;
    public ExistsModifierInterceptor()
    {
        existsModificationVisitor = new ExistsModificationVisitor();
    }
    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        existsModificationVisitor.Syntax.Clear();
        sql.Visit(existsModificationVisitor);
        if (existsModificationVisitor.isModified)
        {
            return base.OnPrepareStatement(existsModificationVisitor.Syntax.ToSqlString());
        }
        else { return base.OnPrepareStatement(sql); }
    }

    internal class ExistsModificationVisitor : ISqlStringVisitor
    {
        public SqlStringBuilder Syntax { get { return _Syntax; } }
        public bool isModified { get; private set; }

        private readonly SqlStringBuilder _Syntax = new SqlStringBuilder();
        private const string ExistKeyword = "exists";
        private const string FromKeyword = "from";
        public ExistsModificationVisitor() { }
        void ISqlStringVisitor.Parameter(Parameter parameter)
        {
            _Syntax.AddParameter();
        }

        public void String(string text)
        {
            if (text.Contains("exists"))
            {
                isModified = true;
                var start = text.IndexOf(ExistKeyword, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                var end = text.IndexOf(FromKeyword, start);
                text = text.Remove(start, end - start);
                text = text.Insert(start, "EXISTS (SELECT 1 ");
            }
                _Syntax.Add(text);
        }
        public void String(SqlString sqlString)
        {
            this.String(sqlString.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I've modified/compiled **HqlExists** in the source with following modification to strip the token and replace it with **HqlIntegerConstant** whichs is a bit faster but I was hoping I wouldn't have to use my own fork for such a small requirement:

```cs
public class HqlExists : HqlBooleanExpression
{
    public HqlExists(IASTFactory factory, HqlQuery query) : base(HqlSqlWalker.EXISTS, "exists", factory, query)
    {
        var selectClauseNode =
                this.Children.FirstOrDefault()?
                    .Children.FirstOrDefault()?
                    .Children.Where(x => x.AstNode.Type == 111).FirstOrDefault();
                selectClauseNode.ClearChildren();
                //Note: AddChild is internal therefore not available outside HqlTreeNode.cs 
                selectClauseNode.AddChild(new HqlIntegerConstant(factory, "1"));
        
    }
    
}
```

Is there a simple way to target and replace explicity the way HqlExists is applied for a given dialect?  I am using **FluentNHibernate** for configuration

Answer (score -1):

This is mostly a duplicate of [HQL "exists" generates invalid SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802294/hql-exists-generates-invalid-sql), but there was no real or accepted answer there.

Have you tried the following?

... where exists (select 1 from YourEntity ...)

... where exists (select e.Id.OneProp from YourEntity e)

I.e. essentially what you would need to write if you wrote the SQL yourself, but in HQL.

Comment: The context of the question has been missed by this submission.  You're restating the approaches already attempted.